# How can I convert Javadoc's output to MediaWiki and place it in SourceForge's wiki?

Tags: java, javadoc, mediawiki, sourceforge

Background:
I'm a novice to open source and SourceForge. Me and a friend of mine are running our final year computer science project from the web site. The project is Java based, and we are using the Java docs in our project.

Actual question:
I wonder if there is any "good" way to convert the Java docs to the MediaWiki format and sync the pages in the Wiki web app that Source Forge has to offer?

Comment: Just a note: Wikimedia is the organization which manages Wikipedia and other projects. MediaWiki is the wiki software (developed under the hoods of Wikimedia).

Comment: You are right, how was this miss represented?

Comment: I already corrected it with an edit (you can see the differences clicking on the "edited ... mins ago" link). Sorry, I should have said this, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same idea and started developing a doclet for mediawiki-integration with help from the [jwbf](http://jwbf.sourceforge.net/)-library.

Examples, source and documentation is available under: http://wiki.rudin.li/index.php/JWikiDoc
The self-documentation is available there too...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find if (and how) sourceforge offers web hosting for projects, but I think it does (see http://pmd.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html, for example, which is the javadoc of PMD, a Java project hosted at sourceforge).

Anyway, I wouldn't try to convert tha javadoc HTML pages to the wikimedia format. Instead, I would host the javadoc HTML pages somewhere (at sourceforge.net if it's possible, elsewhere if it isn't), and simply link to the javadoc from the wiki.

Comment: I don't want to leave the scope of source forge, that is why I want the java docs to be integrated inside SF wiki.

Comment: As I said, I'm pretty sure SourceForge allows you to host your javadoc HTML files. See the PMD example. Its URL is pmd.sourceforge.net.